# Gzip is enabled in developers tools but not working in Google Chrome light house

Tags: apache-2.4, google-chrome, chrome

Here is the website is am working on
Website: https://www.mayfairparking.co.uk

gzip is enabled and chrome shows in developer tools which is fine and as per my expectations but when i test on light house it gives me text compression error message see screenshots below.

Gzip compression enabled in developer tools here is the proof:
[image]

Light House Screenshot on Compression:
[image]

Htaccess Code:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```

any one can suggest why this is happening? and what is the possible fix?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your screenshot of the developer tools only shows the request headers, indicating that your browser accepts compressed responses. It shows nothing about compressing the response.

Comment: Is mod_deflate or mod_gzip enabled?

Comment: I agree with gerald in default configuration it's not enabled.

Comment: you guys were right, deflate module was not enabled on server let me post answer of it to help others. many many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per instructions of Gerald Schneider &  djdomi

i checked status of the server and find out this module was not enabled so followed following instructions?

1. Open your Apache configuration file, which is typically located at **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf or /etc/httpd/conf.d/deflate.conf.**
   Add or modify the following lines within the appropriate  block to specify which file types should be compressed:
2. added following lines in it

   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/javascript
3. and restarted the apache

that's it.